# Why is my Dictionary adding extra escape characters to a string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string, debugging, dictionary

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="1" value="An error occured.\r\nPlease try again later." />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string key = "1";

keyValuePairs.Add(key, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]);

if (keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(key))
{
  // when I hover over the object, keyValuePairs, in my debugger, I see, "An error occured.\r\nPlease try again later."
  string value1 = keyValuePairs[key];
  // now when I hover over the local variable, value, I see, "An error occured.\\r\\nPlease try again later."
}
```

**I'm curious as to why the above code adds escape characters to "\r\n" to make it "\r\n"**

***I'd also like to know how to avoid getting the extra "\" characters.***

Comment: what happens if you use `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: I can't put `Environment.NewLine` in my App.config

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594160/consider-displaying-strings-in-the-debugger-without-escaping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading the string from the app.config, I assume it's something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="errorString" value="An error occured.\r\nPlease try again later."/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In which case your sample code should look like this:

```
keyValuePairs.Add("1", @"An error occured.\r\nPlease try again later.");
```

And from there it should be obvious why the debugger is displaying as it does (especially if you read [JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632130/why-is-my-dictionary-adding-extra-escape-characters-to-a-string/3632148#3632148).

You're better off using a resource dictionary for storing the string, which will easily let you insert newline characters in the VS editor.

Edit: Just on a whim, I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="errorString" value="An error occured.
Please try again later."/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Compiled fine and produced the correct results.

Comment: absolutely correct on both questions: #1 that reading from App.config (AKA XML file) is equivalent to `@""` because it implicitly escapes the `"\"` character, #2 simply typing a carriage return into the App.config fixes my problem.  Thanks.  *(JaredPar's answer had nothing to do with my question.)*

Comment: Also, JaredPar is correct to.  The debugger displays `value1` with `"\\r\\n"` which is the actual value after it gets read in from the App.config.  However, the debugger displays the `Dictionary` contents by hiding the extra slashes: `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 6):

The dictionary isn't doing anything to your string.  The debugger, or more specifically the expression evaluator, will alter the format of a displayed string when it contains newline characters.  The end goal is to make it display better on the single line the debugger typically has for values.

I recently did a blog post which goes into detail about what the debugger does and the reason behind the design

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/06/08/newlines-in-the-immediate-window.aspx

**EDIT**

I believe there is a bug in your sample code.  I think you left at `@` symbol off of the value in the add of the Dictionary.  Without the `@` symbol I do not get your repro but with it I do.  Assuming the `@` is missing though ...

The reason why you see the string with extra escapes is that the debugger always displays strings as string literals and not verbatim strings.  In a string literal you need the double escape to match the equivalent code in the verbatim string.  Hence `\n` becomes `\\n`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not entirely convinced.  My problem is that I don't want the extra slashes added to my newline characters.

Comment: @JohnB, Added some more context to explain why double slashes would appear.

Comment: I am not using @"" - I do understand that @ escapes special characters for you.  I will do more testing later, I have to leave now.  Thanks.

Comment: @JaredPar: how come I see "\\r\\n" when I hover over `value`?

Comment: @JohnB, if the `\\` are showing then the `\` character is being inserted directly into the string and is not a part of an escape sequence.  I've tried the posted repro a Visual Studio 2010 and don't see the behavior unless I make it a verbatim string.