# ReadLine() inserts '\' but I don't want them. (Console App)

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm was trying to write a quick and dirty console application utility to find ObjectName in file and then set all occurrences of Application Name to the ObjectName.

Object name is  a simple string `[ DTS:ObjectName="CT Load AdmissionSource" ]`
But Application Name is embedded in a connection string.

```
DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=r04phidwh62;Initial Catalog=V5DW;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=ETL Lab test;Trust Server Certificate=True;" />
```

When I `ReadLine()` and try and get a substring I'm getting extra '\' characters which is tripping me up when I set pn.

Is there some way I can set pn without those \ characters `ReadLine()` injects?

example:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"   <== extra \
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

.

```
     System.IO.StreamReader file =
                 new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\Transforms\" + files[i]);
                 string pn = "";
                 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                 {
                     if (line.Contains("DTS:ObjectName"))
                     {
                         if (pn.Length == 0)
                          {
                           pn = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("=") + 1);
                           System.Console.WriteLine(pn);
}
                        }
                        if (line.Contains("Application Name"))
                        {
                            string output = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("Application Name=") + 17);
                            if (output.Contains("-{"))
                            {
                                output = output.Substring(0, output.IndexOf("-{"));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                output = output.Substring(0, output.IndexOf(";"));
                            }
                            System.Console.WriteLine(output);
                            line= Regex.Replace(line, @"\"+ output +"\b", pn);
                            outputfile.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                    file.Close();
                    outputfile.Close();
                    System.Console.ReadLine();
                    File.Delete(@"D:\Transforms\" + files[i]);
                    File.Move(@"D:\Transforms\output.txt", @"D:\Transforms\" + files[i]);
                }
```

Comment: Where are you “getting extra '\' characters”? In the debugger or on the console? The debugger shows strings in the language you are programming in, so in C# the string `Hello` will display as `"Hello"` with quotes and `DTS="Hello"` will display as `"DTS=\"Hello\""`. The quotes and backslashes are there to show otherwise-invisible metacharacters and are not part of the string.

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3632148/3538012

Comment: I'm in debug mode but in the application they're making their way into pn when I set it.  pn = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("=") + 1);

If I simply System.Console.WriteLine(line); they aren't there as you say.  So the question is how to set a variable with the substring extract where I don't have them.

Comment: Maybe I should have included more of my code but I get an error when I try to replace text.
{"parsing \"\\CT Load AdmissionSource\b\" - Unrecognized escape sequence \\C."}

on line

line= Regex.Replace(line, @"\"+ output +"\b", pn);

Comment: Maybe my issue is in the line
line= Regex.Replace(line, @"\"+ output +"\b", pn);
because if I change it to
line= Regex.Replace(line, output , pn);
The problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

It's not doing what you think it is. ReadLine() will *not* add characters that are not part of the stream. Visual Studio will show you those characters when you the view the string in the debugger, but they are not actually part of what's there in memory.